# SVN Can't move ... to ... .svn/entries': Resource busy

Tags: svn

I am getting this error every time I try to update my SVN checkouts.

The closest blog post I could find that was related was this:

http://blog.arc90.com/2008/07/02/fixing-the-cant-move-svntmpentries-to-svnentries-error/

I thought this may have been a fix: `chflags -R nouchg ./` from the top of the SVN checkout in the terminal but no joy.

I have had this before but my fix was to completely delete the SVN checkout in question. However this time it is very high up and our directory structure is huge (using ezpublish) and it would take yonks to check it all back out again.

Has anyone else had this and know how to fix it?

Comment: (i have tried the usual svn cleanup but this just takes about 10minutes and returns the same error message)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Possibly another process has opened that file for writing and has blocked it. Try to find which process is blocking that file, and kill it:

```
fuser .svn/entries
# will output:
# /path/to/.svn/entries:  PID
kill -9 PID
```

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. I was running a mac with versions and Titanium and xcode. I found that bascially those three programs together cause the issue. My resolve... (this bit is embarrassing).. turn off and on again. To prevent the issue from happening again I avoid using versions and titanium together